# Does the Imgur hack affect Stack Exchange users?

Tags: support, imgur

Quoting from the Engadget article, [Image-sharing site Imgur was hacked in 2014](https://www.engadget.com/2017/11/24/imgur-hack/):

> Imgur, a popular picture-sharing site, revealed today [November 24] that it suffered
>   a data breach in 2014, claiming it was just notified of it on November
>   23rd. In a blog post, Imgur said hackers stole email addresses and
>   passwords of 1.7 million user accounts -- a small fraction of its 150
>   million total users.

Does the hack affect Stack Exchange users?  I understand Imgur doesn't have my password, as I use O-Auth, but does Stack Exchange share other information with Imgur (e.g. email)?

Comment: not sure about the downvotes - seems like a reasonable question with a reasonable answer

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no, I don't think it's reasonable to assume SE is sharing our email with its image host.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it does not affect our users. We use Imgur solely for hosting images through an API and your personal information is never shared with them (and as Imgur's blog mentions, they don't even collect PII outside of email and password anyways). Think of it this way: all images are uploaded onto *our* account, and not individual accounts for every user.

Comment: Thank you for a straight forward, non-sarcastic, non-defensive answer.